# parse datetime number in html field

Tags: python

This is a sample of datetime field:

```
1615717137369
```

It means 2 days ago (from 16 march, 13:24)

How can I parse the number?

P.S:
These are some examples:

````
16 15 89 8678037    16 March 16:15 ( 5 min ago)

16 15 89 8259356    16 March 16:08 (12 min ago)

16 15 89 791 8713   16 March 16:03 (17 min ago)
16 15 89 791 4439   16 March 16:03 (17 min ago)
16 15 89 791 0813   16 March 16:03 (17 min ago)


16 15 89 210 4036   16 March 14:20 ( 2  hr ago)


16 15 64 022 8942   13 March       (3 days ago)


16 10 43 350 1644   13 Jan         (2 month ago)
```
````

Comment: Looks like the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (1 Jan 1970 midnight UTC).

Comment: This is better suited to [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Emil said, That is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (1 Jan 1970 midnight UTC).

Comment: So what are you doing the next time you see an unknown time format? Ask another question? Or figure it out yourself?

Comment: @gnasher729 Thank you for your concern, but how many times may I see different time formats?!

Comment: Milliseconds is actually rare outside windows because it is so inappropriate. Therefore: a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The data you have is just a large integer. So you parse it like you would parse any large integer. Now there should be documentation what the integer means - if there is none then you will guess.

If the number was days since a date X, calculate what X would be. If the number was seconds since a date X, calculate what X would be. If the number was nanoseconds since a date X, calculate what X would be. Maybe it's a different unit. Pick what unit gives the most reasonable looking date. For example, if X is the year 1582 (introduction of the Gregorian calendar), that would be quite reasonable.

PS. I hate Windows. Giving dates using milliseconds is perverted IMO.